# How to compare PHP variable to value from PHP array

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to execute an SQL query to pull one column of data from my database into a PHP array, and then search for my session variable in that array. I've printed the contents of my array and it looks like the query is working and is filling the array, but my comparison if `(in_array("$session", $result))` is not working correctly.

I know the string my session variable contains is inside the PHP array. But `$execute` never flips to `FALSE`. Any idea why?

```
$confirm = $_GET['name'];
$execute = TRUE;
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['sessionID'];
$result = array();

    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if(substr($session, 0, 2) === 'DS'){
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT confirmNum FROM  `DSattendance`");
            $sql->execute();
            $result = $sql->fetchAll();

        }
        else if (substr($session, 0, 2) === 'BYOD'){
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT confirmNum FROM BYODattendance");
            $sql->execute();
            $result = $sql->fetchAll();

        }    
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();}

    if (in_array("$session", $result)) {
            echo "true";
            $execute = FALSE;
    }

    if ($execute == FALSE)
            echo "ALREADY REGISTERED";

var_dump($result) yields: 

array(10) { 
[0]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "adfafafafaa" [0]=> string(11) "adfafafafaa" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "adsfafafaff" [0]=> string(11) "adsfafafaff" } 
[2]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "asdfafafafa" [0]=> string(11) "asdfafafafa" } 
[3]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "christrader" [0]=> string(11) "christrader" } 
[4]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "christradfe" [0]=> string(11) "christradfe" } 
[5]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "sadfadfafaf" [0]=> string(11) "sadfadfafaf" } 
[6]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "sadfsfafaaf" [0]=> string(11) "sadfsfafaaf" } 
[7]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "sdfsafsadfa" [0]=> string(11) "sdfsafsadfa" } 
[8]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "trraafafafa" [0]=> string(11) "trraafafafa" } 
[9]=> array(2) { ["confirmNum"]=> string(11) "wesdfdfasfa" [0]=> string(11) "wesdfdfasfa" } }
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($result);`? Odds are it'll be returning a multi-dimensional array, thus why your `in_array` isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDO Statement `fetchAll` is returning a multi-dimensional array of the results found in the database. You need to loop through them first and format a new array that you can use to check your session against.

```
foreach($result as $value) {
    $array[] = $value['confirmNum'];
}

if( in_array($session, $array)) {
    // your code here
}
```

As noted by @mr12086, depending on the version of PHP you are using, you can avoid the `foreach` loop by using: `$result = array_column('confirmNum', $result);` instead. However, this does require PHP 5.5.0 or higher.

Comment: Depending on php version you could replace the loop with $result = array_column('confirmNum', $result); for less code.

Comment: Absolutely @mr12086, thanks for adding. I updated my answer to include your response as well. Credit given :)

Comment: @user2977729 np, glad to help.